# Getstream.io: Message format for deleted activities via socket/faye

Tags: websocket, faye, getstream-io

I am implementing something like Facebook reactions via getstream.io.
Posting and removing activities ("reactions") works fine.

**Basics:**

- While implementing the socket feature (faye) of getstream to reflect feed changes in realtime, I saw that the format of a socket message for new activities differs from the one for deleted activities.

**Example having ONE reaction each in deleted and new:**

```
{
  "deleted": [
    "d5b1aee0-5a1a-11e6-8080-80015eb61bf9",
    "49864f80-5a19-11e6-8080-80015eb61bf9",
    "47fe7700-5a19-11e6-8080-80015eb61bf9",
    "4759ab80-5a19-11e6-8080-80015eb61bf9",
    "437ce680-5a19-11e6-8080-80015eb61bf9"
  ],
  "new": [
    {
      "actor": "user:55d4ab8a11234359b18f06f6:Manuel Reil",
      "verb": "support",
      "object": "control:56bf2fb884e5c0756e910755",
      "target": null,
      "time": "2016-08-04T11:48:23.168000",
      "foreign_id": "55d4ab8a11234359b18f06f6:support:56bf2fb884e5c0756e910755",
      "id": "58d9c000-5a39-11e6-8080-80007c3c41d8",
      "to": [],
      "origin": "control:56bf2fb884e5c0756e910755"
    }
  ],
  "published_at": "2016-08-04T11:48:23.546708+00:00"
}
```

- I subscribe to the  *aggregated* feed that follows a flat feed.
- I add and remove activities via the flat feed.
- Subscriptions to the flat and the aggregated feed both return the same message when adding and removing activities.

**Challenges I am facing:**

- When I remove ONE activity (via `foreign_id`) - why do appear 5 ids in the deleted array?
- I need to have the foreign_id to reflect changes in the app while digesting the socket message from gestream.io. This works fine for new activities as the full object is sent (see example above). However, for the deleted activities they are missing as just an array of `ids` is sent.

**Potential approaches:**

- Can I somehow configure my getstream faye subscription or config to (also) return `foreign_ids`for the deleted items?
- I could try to fetch those `ids` in addition based on the socket message, but this seems almost ridiculous.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing activities via `foreign_id` deletes all the activities with the given foreign_id present in the feed. This is one of the main upsides of using the foreign_id field, it allows for cascading deletes to a group of activities. (eg. Post and Likes is a typical use-case where you want to delete one Post and all Likes related to it).

Another advantage of using foreign_id is that you don't have to keep track of the ID generated by Stream.

You should be able to solve your first problem by picking a value for the `foreign_id` field that is unique (eg. the object ID from your database), this way you can still delete easily and avoid the cascaded delete behavior.

Regarding your second problem, if you are updating your UI based on the the real-time updates it also means you already read from the same feed, and that you have the list of activities with their IDs and foreign_ids. Selecting activities from activity_id should be just a matter of creating some sort of in memory map (eg. add an data-activity_id attribute to your DOM).

Comment: Super quick answer - thank you. Ad 1) Removing via foreign_id is cool. Ad 2) As I am displaying and working on the aggregated feed. So the ids are not useful there. But I could retrieve the flat feed as well and build a hashmap from there. Do you know any better idea for the aggregated feed case?